# Constructing a tree in LaTeX

Tags: labels, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

I am having real trouble creating a tree. So far I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node,
   level distance=1.25cm,sibling distance=1cm,
   edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}]
\Tree
[
    \edge node[auto=right,pos=.6] {$A$};
    [.1
       \edge node[auto=right,pos=.8] {$B$};
       [.2 ]
       \edge node[auto=left,pos=.8] {$C$};
       [.3 ]
        ]
    \edge node[auto=left,pos=.6] {$D$};
    [.4 ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

However, I want to have two more layers, from 2 I want another 2 branches, and from the left of these branches I want another.
Also how does one put a label underneath the numbers I have used?

Thank you very much and I hope I am clear

Comment: Use the [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package.

Comment: Please make your code compilable by including `\documentclass`, relevant packages, etc.

Comment: How exactly do you want the labels underneath the numbers? Can you add to your question an image (even a hand-drawn image) of the intended tree?

Comment: Packages loaded were tikz, qtree and tikz-qtree.

Comment: I am unable to provide a picture, i would just like underneath each node a place i could put some text.

Comment: @user70498 I've provided an answer below. I also edited your question to turn your code into a fully compilable MWE and added an image of the output. I hope that's OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package instead; it's more versatile, it has a lot of built-in features to customize trees and will give you shorter code. A simple example showing multi-line nodes:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  l sep=30pt,
  parent anchor=south,
  align=center
}
[
  [1\\some text,edge label={node[midway,left]{A}}
    [2\\some text,edge label={node[midway,left]{B}}
      [4\\some text,edge label={node[midway,left]{C}}
        [6\\some text,edge label={node[midway,left]{D}}
        ]
        [7\\some text,edge label={node[midway,right]{E}}
        ]
      ]
      [5\\some text,edge label={node[midway,right]{F}}
      ]
    ]
    [3\\some text,edge label={node[midway,right]{G}}
    ]
  ]
  [8\\some text,edge label={node[midway,right]{H}}
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfecto! Thank you, i shall use the forrest command from now on.

Comment: @user70498 You're welcome! Don't forget that, after a sensible wait, you can accept the answer in case you consider it solved your problem. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).